# How to enable debugging in a particular app in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, server

I want to enable Django debugging in a particular apps in the whole project because when the site is go to production if found something anything bug then I will fix by enabling the debug in the particular view in Django app without affecting the other modules
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this can be done- but it probably shouldn't be done.

Exposing even a single app in `debug` mode could potentially leak security keys and more likely just lead to unexpected behavior, especially because django tries its best to prevent you from enabling debug mode outside of the development webserver.

Use proper logging within your app to report and replicate errors and avoid debug in production. There various 3rd party services that can be very easily installed on your webserver and handle most of the error and traceback logging for you- likely at no cost (assuming you don't have thousands of errors to process).